# How to receive email via IMAP protocol in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, imap

What is the best way to receive email via IMAP protocol in Rails 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure about best, but a simple way is to use [`Net::IMAP`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/net/imap/rdoc/index.html). You can write a `rake` task and periodically poll the mailbox for emails by using a scheduler like `cron`.

So your setup would look like this:

1. A library file which servers as a wrapper for `IMAP` client and other related operations, like processing the emails.
2. The `rake` task which when called downloads the emails and processes them using the wrapper mentioned above.
3. The scheduler (Cron or any other of your choice. I personally always prefer `cron`) which periodically calls this `rake` task.

Answer (score 0):

As per `ActionMailer`'s documentation the solution is to have the email forwarded to your rails application and implement `UserMailer.receive(STDIN.read)` to process the email.

The documentation ([Action Mailer Basics](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html)) doesn't sound very convincing about this approach.  It's not telling where the call should be implemented but I guess that would be at the MTA level.

Comment: Also, while I am new to `Ruby on Rails` and `Ruby`, I am not sure what would be the benefits of using `Rails` as compared to a vanilla `Ruby`.

Comment: Another thought, not that I am expecting large volumes but I do not like the idea of calling a program for each emails. I'll go with implementing a `Ruby` application using `Net::IMAP` that listen for new emails (and doesn't have to connect to the DB for each email).